# Getting html form data using http

Tags: html, node.js, forms, http

I need to get data from simple html form (code below) and send it to API (http://netology.tomilomark.ru/doc/#api-ND) that makes hash out of it.
Here is html form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="/sendForm">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
    <br>
    Surname:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
</body>
```

And that's what I´ve got on the server side:

```
"use strict";

const http        = require("http");
const fs          = require("fs");
const PORT        = 3000;

let resObject = {};
let hash;
// Code that sends name + surname to the API and creates hash 
// ------------- begin -------------
let options = {
  hostname: "netology.tomilomark.ru",
  path: "/api/v1/hash",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "firstName": "Evgeny",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
};

let req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  let resString = "";
  res.on("data", (data) => {
    resString += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    console.log(resString);
    hash = resString["hash"];
  })
});

let reqMessage = JSON.stringify({"lastName": "Kobzev"});

req.write(reqMessage);
req.end();

resObject.firstName = "Evgeny";
resObject.lastName = "Kobzev";
console.log(JSON.stringify(resObject));
// -------------- end --------------

// Create web server that loads the html file
// ------------- begin -------------
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile("./logs/form.html", (err, file) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':file.length});
    res.write(file);
  });
});
server.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
server.on("listening", () => console.log(`Start HTTP on port ${PORT}`));
server.listen(PORT);
// -------------- end --------------
```

How can I get data from that simple form and later send it to API? The problem is that I need to use a low level abstraction solution: http and maybe querystring.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You want to get the names in response or hashed values???Or simply you want the data that you entered in form????

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe this API gives me hash + value like this: {"hash":"04c1bc3782871a2801abf121e3ea45f8"}. I can later pack my name, surname, hash into a object. There is no problems with that

Answer (score 1):

After working for few minutes I get the code.Here in my code I am printing hash values in terminal.And here is my code

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var request=require('request');
var util=require('util');
const http= require("http");
const fs= require("fs");
var hash=require('object-hash');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/sendForm' && req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = "";
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
    });
  req.on('end', function () {
  var post= qs.parse(body);
    var Fs=hash({NAME:post.firstName});
    var Sn=hash({SURNAME:post.surName});
    console.log("FirstName:"+post.firstName);
    console.log("SurName:"+post.surName)
    console.log("Hashed Value Of FirstName:"+Fs);
    console.log("Hashed Value Of SurName:"+Sn);
  res.end("successfully submitted");
     });

    }
 fs.readFile("./sample.html", (err, file) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html','Content-Length':file.length});
  res.end(file);

  });
 }).listen(3000,function(){
     console.log("Server Listening on 3000");
 });
```

Hope this helps for you...